# Socket closed error when trying to socket write (bytearray)

Tags: javascript, java, arrays, sockets, serversocket

The code below triggers the following error:

**Error: Exception when sending command: Socket closed**

```
    public synchronized void sendCommand(final ServerCommand pServerCommand) {

    if (pServerCommand == null) {
        return;
    }

    try {
        //byte array to write server command
        ByteArrayOutputStream baosData = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        DataOutputStream osData = new DataOutputStream(baosData);
        //byte array that will be used to write on socket
        //this will contain length of ByteArrayData and then ByteArrayData
        ByteArrayOutputStream baosOut = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        DataOutputStream osOut = new DataOutputStream(baosOut);

        //write command into osData byte array
        pServerCommand.write(osData);
        //write length of command into main byte array
        osOut.writeShort(baosData.size());
        //write command into main byte array
        baosData.writeTo(baosOut);

        OutputStream out = this.getSocket()
                               .getOutputStream();
        //write main byte array on socket
        byte[] data = baosOut.toByteArray();
        out.write(data, 0, data.length);
        out.flush();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.pt("Exception when sending command", e.getMessage());
        // Socket is possibly closed
    }

}
```

Comment: Please provide more details and context. What are you trying o do? When does it happen and with what frequency?
And most importantly please try to state the problem so it can help other people that come across a similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

For whatever reason, the socket to which you are writing is closed. Either it was not opened, it was closed already on your end, or it was closed on the other end, apparently a server.

A couple of suggestions. First, move all the data prep code to a method that returns a byte[]. Socket code is hard enough without mixing it with code that manipulates data.

Second, make sure the socket was actually opened. That's not a given.